# Date format messed up while copying data from one spreadsheet to another using Google Sheets API batchUpdate

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am copying a dataset from one spreadsheet to another and all is fine except the dates.
In the source file the dates are like "2020-07-27", but after I run the script, the dates in the destination file are in completely different format like "Sun Jul 26 18:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020".
What should I do in order to copy the date as it is - YYYY-MM-DD?

My code:

```
  function myFunction() {
    
      var sheet_source_values = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JfjXPPFj08p6cxjdsdcBhTMkl6yXLJkhASG0dv4").getSheetByName(Utilities.formatDate(now,"GMT+1", "dd.MM")).getRange('A:AD').getValues()
      var sheet_destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GTjEfvjoTJ7U7ZXwYUEnSkKtfudXZuCP0dyq").getSheetByName("Updated_sheet")
      
var request = {
        'responseValueRenderOption' : 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE',
        'valueInputOption': 'RAW',
        'responseDateTimeRenderOption' : 'SERIAL_NUMBER',
        'data': [
          {
            'range': "'Updated_sheet'!" + sheet_destination.getRange(2,1,sheet_source_values.length,sheet_source_values[0].length).getA1Notation(),
            'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
            'values': sheet_source_values
          }
        ]
      };
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, "GTjEfvjoTJ7U7ZXwYUEnSkKtfudXZuCP0dyq");
    }
```

I tried changing "responseValueRenderOption" and "responseDateTimeRenderOption" but could find solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem here is not with the Sheets API, but with the way you are retrieving the values from the source spreadsheet.**

According to the `getValues` method documentation:

> `getValues` - Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column. The values may be of type `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String`, depending on the value of the cell.

In this way, the values will be retrieved as a `Date` type, but this type is the Google default one, hence the results you are getting on the destination sheet.

In order to fix this, I suggest you use `getDisplayValues` instead as this will return the displayed values from the source sheet. As for the Sheets API request, you can simply keep the `'valueInputOption': 'RAW'` option only.

**Modified `sheet_source_values`**

```
var sheet_source_values = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bGCXCUe6cgyLQRUQrOIAT2BruBH95ybAX7iG_pyk4Q0").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange('A1:A4').getDisplayValues();
```

**Modified Sheets API request**

```
var request = {
    'valueInputOption': 'RAW',
    'data': [{
        'range': "'Updated_sheet'!" + sheet_destination.getRange(2, 1, sheet_source_values.length, sheet_source_values[0].length).getA1Notation(),
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': sheet_source_values
    }]
};
```

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script Range Class - getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues);
- [Google Apps Script Range Class - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It is now showing the date in the correct format! 
BUT, another problem came up. The destination file shows the correct format of date, but with a " ' " as a first digit before DATES and NUMBERS.

Number like 120,000 shows like this: '120,000
Date like 12/12/2020 shows like this: '12/12/2020

Comment: Ok, nevermind, just needed to change 'valueInputOption': 'RAW' to 'USER_ENTERED' and it's fine. Once again thank you